# Reversing word with Stack

Tags: java, stack, reverse

I am not sure why this is giving me an error. I am in the method pop and i want to return the value stored at the position top. Though it says they are incompatible types. I do not see why it should be a problem as I only want the character to be printed out at the position. This is part of a bigger program just so you know and will be getting the word from a different class.

```
public class Stack
{
private int maxSize;
private String[] stackArray;
private int top;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Stack
 */
    public Stack(int a)
    {
      maxSize = a;
      stackArray = new String [maxSize];
       top = -1;
    }

   public void push(String j)
   {
     top++;
     stackArray[top] = j;
   }  

   public char pop()
   {
     return stackArray[top--];//Error is here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stackArray` is a `string` array and the return type of your method is `char`.

---

> Reversing word with Stack

If you want to reverse a word with your `Stack` object, consider using a `char` array and not a `String array`.

```
class Stack
{
private int maxSize;
private char[] stackArray;
private int top;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Stack
 */
    public Stack(int a)
    {
      maxSize = a;
      stackArray = new char [maxSize];
       top = -1;
    }

   public void push(char j)
   {
     top++;
     stackArray[top] = j;
   }  

   public char pop()
   {
     return stackArray[top--];
   }

   public int getSize(){
     return maxSize;
   }
}
```

And the following test case :

```
        String s = "test";
        Stack st = new Stack(s.length());
        
        for(char c : s.toCharArray())
            st.push(c);
        
        for(int i = 0; i <st.getSize();i++)
            System.out.print(st.pop());
```

Output :

```
tset
```

Comment: Is your test case in a main class or in the Stack class?

Comment: That simplifies it so much. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way to do the question without using the getSize method?

Comment: well you could remove this method because you know that the size of the array in the stack will be the length()or your original word.

Comment: Ye I figured it out by using i<word.length()
Thanks again, I should really start looking this stuff up more instead of hitting my head off a brick wall.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing `String`s onto your array (which is an array of `String`s), and trying to pop a `char`. Change your method to

```
public String pop() {
    return stackArray[top--];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not know how I did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

Your signature says you are returning a char, but you are returning a String.

change

```
public char pop()
```

to

```
public String pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

- In the `pop` method, return the char you want from the top string
- where you call `pop`, get the char from the String that was returned from `pop`.

The second choice is probably the better of the two as one would expect `pop` to return whatever type is on the stack.