# array will not take in a user designated value

Tags: java, arrays

Why is my stringArray not allowed be equal to the word in this piece of code? I have asked the user to put in the word they want, declared as a String and then I have made an array, also of type String. Is it simply I have my declarations wrong?

```
public class Lab8 {
  public static void main() {
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a word to reverse:");
    String word = scan1.nextLine();

    String stackArray = new String[word];  
    //Stack stack1= new Stack();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        stack1.push(word.substring(i,i++));
    }

    String strRev = "";
    while (!stack1.isEmpty()) {
        strRev += stack1.pop();
    }
    System.out.println("Reversed: " + strRev);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note : According to your previous question, you should use a stack of char to reverse a word instead of having a stack of Strings and doing `stack1.push(word.substring(i,i++));` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200607/reversing-word-with-stack

Comment: I am only tinkering with the code. Thanks. I am just seeing what other ways to do it :)

Comment: -1 because the error has not been identified - and there are several, like *it won't even compile*.

Answer (score 1):

```
String stackArray = new String[word];
```

This line isn't making much sense. To declare an array we use `[]` after the array name. To specify a size we use an integer value, not string. The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

For example: a declaration `int[] arr;` and `int arr[];` both declare `arr` as an array of integer. However, a declration statement like:

```
int[] arr1, arr2, arr3;
```

will declare all `arr1, arr2, arr3` as an array of integer. While a declaration like:

```
int arr1[], arr2;
```

will declare `arr1[]` as an array of integer and `arr2` as an `int` variable.

For your context however,

```
String stackArray[] = new String[word.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String stackArray[] = word.split("");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors here.

```
String word = scan1.nextLine();

int word_len = word.length();

String[] stackArray = new String[word_len];
```

This should work.

Edit: Tip o' the cap to @user2864740

Comment: I imagine it should be `new String[word.length()]`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm now seeing that OP wants to get each character out of the word. Brain cramp on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Your array construct is wrong (needs `[]`), also push in `for` loop is wrong, you increment `i` in multiple places, will lead to wrong result.